# Issue with the initialization of a large, dynamically allocated array

Tags: memory-management, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have two versions of the same Fortran code:

Version 1 (static allocation):

```
  program main
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: n=1000000
  integer,parameter :: m=10000
  real(8) a(n,m)
  a=0.d0
  end
```

Version 2 (dynamic allocation):

```
  program main
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: n=1000000
  integer,parameter :: m=10000
  real(8),allocatable :: a(:,:)
  allocate(a(n,m))
  a=0.d0
  end
```

What is the reason that Version 1 does its job immediately, while Version 2 spends a considerable amount of time on the initialization statement, `a=0.d0`?
Another strange effect is that the RES memory usage continuously increases during the initialization of array `a`.

Is there a way to allocate array a dynamically without significantly increasing the CPU time?

**UPDATE #1:**

If I add `write(*,*) a(1,1)` to Version 1, then I receive the following compilation error:

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o): in function `for__process_start_time':
for_init.c:(.text+0xc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `for_process_start_time'
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o): in function `handle_flt_und':
for_init.c:(.text+0x3d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_fpe_mask' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
for_init.c:(.text+0x344): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_undcnt' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
for_init.c:(.text+0x396): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_undcnt' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
for_init.c:(.text+0x39e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_undcnt' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
for_init.c:(.text+0x3aa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_excpt_info' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
for_init.c:(.text+0x3cb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_excpt_info' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
for_init.c:(.text+0x41e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `for__l_undcnt' defined in .bss section in /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o)
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.2/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libifcoremt.a(for_init.o): in function `for__signal_handler':
for_init.c:(.text+0x91a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
for_init.c:(.text+0x944): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
for_init.c:(.text+0x961): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
ld: failed to convert GOTPCREL relocation; relink with --no-relax
```

This extra statement, however, does not cause any issue for Version 2.

**UPDATE #2:**

Both codes were compiled with the default `ifort` options (which includes `-O2`). If I use `-O0` when compiling Version 1, then I obtain a similar error for Version 1 as displayed above.

**UPDATE #3:**

I managed to solve the compilation error by including the flag `-mcmodel=medium`.

With this extra flag, the initialization takes some time in Version 1, as well (indicating that Version 1 was skipped previously `a=0.d0` due to `-O2`).
However, Version 1 is still two times faster than Version 2 (both with or without optimization).
Is that normal?
Furthermore, Version 1 seems to grab only 37 GB memory instead of 74.6 GB (the latter should be more reasonable for the actual array size).
It's not clear to me why 37 GB is sufficient for Version 1.

Comment: Can you show us how you compiled this? What happens if you Write the array to a file at the end ? An optimiser could recognise that  this program has no output and just emit a NOP to be run.

Comment: Also note real(8) is not portable, may not do what you expect, and is not guaranteed to be supported by your compiler. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: @IanBush  They were compiled in the same way, with the default settings: `ifort -o code.x code.f`, without additional optimization.

Comment: It used to be the case that unfortunately ifort had -O2 as the default - this may well be the case still (I don't use ifort very often). Could you *edit the question*  to include this information, please, and also tell us what happens if you use the array after you have initialised it by, for example, writing it to a file,

Comment: @IanBush I did it, with some additional updates.

Comment: When I compare the assembly code for these two versions, the initialization code is the same. It could be that the allocation takes a long time, for some reason. To be honest, I had expected the compiler to evaporate the whole thing because the value of the array was never used, but it doesn't.

Comment: @SteveLionel So can you confirm that the initialization takes place in both versions? Do you know what causes the error with -O0 is added and how to remedy this?

Comment: @SteveLionel By the way, the statement `allocate(a(n,m))` is executed immediately and only `a=0.d0` is slow.  It's also strange for me that the memory usage is growing rapidly after the allocation statement.

Comment: It's not strange: when some memory is allocated, it remains "virtual" until it is actually accessed, i.e. no page is associated. Once accessed, it becomes "resident", i.e. some pages are attributed. Pages are typically 4096 bytes large, and pages are gradually attributed while the array is filled.

Comment: Your array is 80 Gb large: I doubt it can be statically allocated. And for the dynamic version: how much RAM do you have, and what is the size of your swap space?

Comment: @PierU I managed to do the static allocation after I included `-mcmodel=medium` (therewith solving the compilation error found previously). With this extra flag, the initialization is indeed slower in Version 1 (which indicates that Version 1 completely ingored a=0.d0 due to `-O2`). However, Version 1 is still two times faster than Version 2 (both with or without optimization). Is that normal? Furthermore, Version 1 seems to grab only 37 GB memory instead of 74.6 GB (the latter should be more reasonable for the actual array size). It's not clear to me why 37 GB is sufficient for Version 1.

Comment: @PierU The memory specification of the node used is the following: ` total:  5.9Ti`  `used: 146Gi`  `free: 4.0Ti`  `shared: 10Mi`  `buff/cache: 1.8Ti` `available: 5.7Ti`.

Comment: 6 TB of RAM? Not usual at least :)... But is it all DRAM, or is it a [unified memory](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/memory-storage/optane-persistent-memory/optane-dc-persistent-memory-brief.html) with some high performance SSD that is merged with the actual DRAM? This could explain the difference in initialization time, depending on where the array is allocated (but it would not explain the 37GB vs 75GB).

Comment: @PierU Yes, this is a great device bought for finding dominant eigenvalues of very large (10^9 times 10^9) matrices, which are not stored explicitly, but available through vector-matrix multiplications. I am not familiar with the composition of this supercomputer, but I have not heard SSDs in relation with memory in our group. Anyway, Version 1 is really weird due to 37 GB, which is much smaller than 10 billion doubles in my head.

Comment: I have tested your pieces of code with ifort 21. I don't have such a large RAM, so I have dimensioned the array to 100000x10000 (8GB). The two versions occupy the same amount of resident memory (about 8GB), and the initialization of the array take about the same time.

Comment: If this is a machine at Oxford I am aware of the memory subsytem is somewhat strange, and for a given core some of the memory can truly be *very* distant, which could definitely result in some strange effects. I'm not saying this is the case, I can't know here, but for such a large memory configuration and array quite how the array maps onto the physical hardware will be crucial. But I don't feel qualified to say more than that.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks Ian. I am trying to digest this strange behavior and see its consequences to my further work. By the way, this computer belongs to our group in Budapest.

Comment: @RolandTóbiás yes, I can confirm that there is a call to an "intel_fast_memset" function in both versions. I had to reduce the static array size as I'm on Windows which doesn't support more than 2GB of static code and data (even on x64). I did not time the versions, though.